# Minimal amount of swaps

Tags: algorithm

Assume we have got sequence (of length `n`) of ones and zeroes, eg. `10100100`. We want to rearrange them, so `1` follows every `0`, and `0` follows every `1` - but in the end there can be some `0`s or `1`s left - so our sequence will become `10101000`. Let's say there is `k` amount of `1` and `n-k` amount of `0`, so we need to have `min(n, n-k)` groups of `10` (or `01`) and then the rest left.

We can do one operations - swap two chosen elements. We need to calculate the minimum amount of swaps to rearrange sequence into given order - e.g. we need just one swap (between indexes `4` and `5`, indexing from `0`), to rearrange that correctly. For `0101011111` or `10101000000` we need `0` swaps.

Any ideas how to calculate that? Any complexity actually would be apprieciated - I got no idea how to do that.

Comment: Do you have any attempts at the question? Even a brute force algorithm? The trivial solution that comes to mind would be `while(not sorted) { swap(random element 1, random element 2) }`, which may or may not complete before the heat death of the universe ;-)

Comment: Do you have to check, whether 10101000 or 01010100 (1st example) needs fewer swaps? Or do you have to search for the fewest swaps for some valid solution?

Comment: Can thinking about the position of ('1')s and about the modulo operation help you?

Comment: O(2n): Parse string to count numbers of 0, 1. Rewrite string, starting with first character, and then alternate 0,1 until one set runs out and then finish the string with the remaining characters. No swapping required.

Comment: @AJD post ur answer, it's the correct approach

Comment: @zenwraight: It's obviously not.

Comment: @userunknown can u prove that it's wrong ? I mean it's correct only right, may be I am missing a corner case here

Comment: @AJD: how do you plan to "rewrite string" when your only available operation is to swap a pair of elements?  You will, indeed, produce a valid solution, but the required number of atomic transformations will not often be minimal.

Comment: @piternet: "In the end" suggests time, not position.  Must the surplus elements appear at the end of the string, or is the starting position of `10100100` a valid solution?

Comment: @zenwraight: It's obviously a question about minimal swap operations, but with just swapping allowed, so zero is in most cases not the right answer. Minimize swapping without avoiding it altogether. "We can do one operation - swap two chosen elements. We need to calculate the minimum amount of swaps to rearrange sequence into given order "

Comment: @userunknown - yes, in my blurry early morning eyes I missed the "we can do one operations". Well, easy to miss in a read of the problem! However, if the only operation is a "swap", how can one verify if the final answer is right?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I'm assuming that your surplus characters *must* appear at the right side of the string.  This means that the previous characters must alternate.  This gives you only two possible solutions for the final string.  In the case you give, these would be

```
10101000
01010100
```

Your entire algorithm is simple: produce both of these sequences (`k` 0's alternating with `k` 1's) and append the `n-k` extras.  Compare each with the original to see which of the two has the smaller quantity of displaced characters.  Identify those pairs and swap.  For instance, using the above:

```
10100100  original
10101000  candidate
--------
....!!..  two differences, one swap

10100100  original
01010100  candidate
--------
!!!!....  four differences, two swaps
```

You use the first candidate, with locations 4 and 5 already identified.

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to collection of Ints:

```
("10100100".toList).map (_.toInt-'0')
= List(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Zip it with index:

```
.zipWithIndex
List((1,0), (0,1), (1,2), (0,3), (0,4), (1,5), (0,6), (0,7))
```

with modulo, find for index (0,1,2...), which value we either expect, (010...) a is string value, b is possible, alternating value of 01, c is index in String

```
.map {case (a,b)=> (a, b%2, b)}
List((1,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,2), (0,1,3), (0,0,4), (1,1,5), (0,0,6), (0,1,7))
```

filter those who match expectation (do the same for those in opposite order, a!=b):

```
.filter {case (a,b,c) => a==b }
List((0,0,4), (1,1,5), (0,0,6))
```

group by alternating value for later counting:

```
.groupBy {case (a,b,c)=> b}
Map(1 -> List((1,1,5)), 0 -> List((0,0,4), (0,0,6)))
```

get the lenghts and count:

```
.map {case (a, b) => (a, b.length)}
Map(1 -> 1, 0 -> 2)
```

Ignore the 1 and 0 as identifier, just take the count:

```
.map (i => (i._2))
List(1, 2)
```

Since we can only perform swaps for 1 where we have a corresponding 0 and vice versa, take the minimum of both:

```
"10100100".toList).map (_.toInt-'0').zipWithIndex.map {case (a,b)=> (a, b%2, b)}.filter {case (a,b,c) => a==b }.groupBy {case (a,b,c)=> b}.map {case (a, b)=> (a, b.length)}.map (i => (i._2)).min
1
```

In the end, we didn't need the c-value, it was just useful for keeping track, what's happening. Here is the version without c, and which starts with 1, not 0:

```
("10100100".toList).map (_.toInt-'0').zipWithIndex.map {case (a,b)=> (a, b%2)}.filter {case (a,b) => a!=b }.groupBy {_._2}.map {case (a, b)=> (a, b.length)}.map (i => (i._2)).min
2
```

The minimum of those two values (1, 2) is the solution.

Comment: But the only operation is a swap? If we could `list`, `zip` and `group`, then the string solution I noted in comments above would also be possible (because a string is merely an ordered list of characters).

Comment: Well, I think that's the practical operation to be done, not the reasoning where to perform the swaps. "Any ideas how to calculate that?" - So the question is, how to calculate the swaps.